# Uploading a file with Nightwatch and Browser Stack / Selenium Grid

Tags: node.js, browserstack, nightwatch

I'm trying to upload a file in a nightwatch test that is being run on Browserstack in IE11. Here is what I have:

```
browser.execute(function (data) {
  const el = document.querySelector('input#fileUpload');
  el.style.display = "block";
  el.removeAttribute('multiple');
}, []);

browser.setValue('input#fileUpload', require('path').resolve(__dirname + '/upload-files/test-doc.pdf'))
```

The error is a file not found issue, it works fine when being run on Chrome locally. Searching around, it seems like I need to upload the file to BS first, I found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Bunk/6c384fbe15556f7702d32aa8aa7a7521) and this [PR](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/890) but neither worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is not present on the machine of BrowserStack you might be encountering this error. You will need to use the '***setFileDetector***' method provided by Selenium to upload a local file to remote grid. More details can be found on their documentation here - https://www.browserstack.com/automate/node#enhancements-uploads-downloads

Comment: Yes, i've also read that but i'm unsure how that translates into nightwatch, which doesn't seem to expose the underlying driver imported by that code directly.

Comment: @ben any newer findings about this issue? Did you fix it?